How do I estimate the mean and variance from data?
I have made a periodogram (plot given below) from some 1D data, and would like to estimate the bias and variance of it. because by minimizing both I could select the ideal window size for calculating my periodogram. I dont have an underlying model, nor do i have the true values/target values to compare to. How would i estimate the bias and variance of the data, for comparison purposes. Can i use the raw periodogram (blue). for that?
For example,

Here the orange and blue curves indicates the same dataset post processed but by changing a variable (window size).
Details regarding the time series:

The time series is non-stationary (The moments of the distributions from which the values are sampled, changes at random intervals.)
The time series is sampled at equal intervals. Its a detector that returns values  at equal intervals in time.
window size: I had to use a window size of 3000 points to get the orange curve. The total time series has 1.7 million data points.

How do i find the best window size. One idea i had was to find it as a pareto optimal solution by find the size at which the bias and variance tradeoff is at a minimum (probably need to weigh them to get some equivalence before making the comparison)?
The slope of the of the segment after the first bend is important for me. And the slope changes with the window size. Hence the search for the best window size!!

Welcome to Cross Validated! What's wrong with the usual sample statistics like $\bar x = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i x_i$ and $s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_i\left(x_i - \bar x\right)^2?$

sorry, Ive updated the question to give a bit more clarity to my question

What is your $x$ and $y$ here on the axis? The labels are currently vague.

What do you mean by "1D data" and how do you define their "mean" and "variance" if not in the usual ways??

I struggle to reconcile the comment about 1D data and the 2D plot of the data. Could you please clarify?

It would help if you could edit the question to say more about the nature of the data and what you are trying to accomplish by things like having "the same dataset post processed but by changing a variable." Sometimes, if you can say what you're trying to accomplish in the bigger picture, there will be a better and well established way to reach your goal.

@EdM I have upadated the question. Sorry for the confusion

That's a good start. Now please edit some more to describe the nature of the (time-series or equivalent) data (Is this from a stationary series? Are data from a single or from multiple series? Sampled regularly or irregularly? Sampled how often? Window sizes you've tried?) and to explain what you are trying to learn from the periodogram.  Recognize that you can't minimize both bias and variance, so also describe what your tradeoffs are between them. I know enough about time series to know that I'm not qualified to answer, but those who are will probably want to know about those matters.

@EdM Ive addressed your questions regarding the time series. Thank you for helping me improve it

It might help to state your ultimate interest up front: "The slope of the segment after the first bend is important for me," and what you want to learn from that. I don't know enough about power spectra/periodograms to provide an answer, but I suspect that there might be a better way to get an estimate of that slope than the way that you are proceeding, particularly with a non-stationary time series. You might also consider changing the title of your question to state your ultimate goal more directly. Then those with the necessary expertise can address the time-series issues.

Might be related: http://rafalab.dfci.harvard.edu/pages/754/section-05.pdf especially the discussion about linear smoothers and their bias variance trade-off.

This isn't a complete answer. It's more a collection of suggestions for further study based on what you're trying to accomplish (which still isn't completely clear to me, at least, from the question) and how you want to deal with your non-stationary data.
First, a raw periodogram from a single time series, even if it's stationary, is almost useless. What you then have is a single sample from some data-generation process, which by itself isn't much different from having a single sample from which to estimate the mean of a distribution. You can't get much generalizable information from it. As it includes just a single sample of the noise in the system it is inherently noisy, as in your example. See this answer, for example.
Second, periodograms from a non-stationary times series aren't reliable. MATLAB documentation puts it clearly:

For nonstationary signals with time-dependent frequency content, the short-time Fourier transform is a better analysis tool.

The spectrogram is a classic method implementing the short-time Fourier transform. There are several other ways to evaluate time-frequency relationships, as illustrated in the MATLAB time-frequency gallery.
Third, it seems that what you care about is bias and variance in your estimate of the slope of the power spectrum on your log-log scale, rather than the "bias and variance of the data." It thus sounds like what you want is covered by Mc Coy et. al, in Multitaper Spectral Estimation
of Power Law Processes, IEEE Transactions on Signal Processing, 46: 655-668, 1998. They summarize their results:

We have demonstrated that the use of the multitaper spectrum estimation method, combined with regression on the resulting estimated spectrum ordinates, provides a sound practical method for estimating a power-law exponent.

This answer invokes the R multitaper package, discussing along the way how a Slepian taper improves upon the simple "boxcar" windowing that you presumably used to get your orange curve, and the additional advantages of multitapering:

The Multitaper Spectral estimator is one of the better estimators because you're using a weighted average of  direct spectral estimates using orthogonal tapers (the Slepians). The extra direct estimates gives you variance reduction and the adaptive weighting provides protection against bias.

Finally, Demirel et al., in the arXiv paper Single-Channel EEG Based Arousal Level Estimation Using Multitaper Spectrum Estimation at Low-Power Wearable Devices, have a situation that seems similar in outline to yours: non-stationary data due to different EEG spectra depending on arousal level, and estimating the power-spectrum slope, over a range of interest, for different arousal levels. They use Slepian multitapers and linear regression in log-log space over a defined frequency range.
